# swift 2.2 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff411c6ef90'

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this [library](https://github.com/okmr-d/DOFavoriteButton) and everything worked fine before I updated to swift 2.2

The first warnings I got was that I had to update my selectors to the new #selector which I have.

But now I get the error:

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Test.DOFavoriteButton select:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff411c6ef90'

When I look in the code I find these functions:

```
public func select() {
    select(true)
}

public func select(animate animate: Bool) {
    selected = true
    imageShape.fillColor = imageColorOn.CGColor

    if animate {
        CATransaction.begin()

        circleShape.addAnimation(circleTransform, forKey: "transform")
        circleMask.addAnimation(circleMaskTransform, forKey: "transform")
        imageShape.addAnimation(imageTransform, forKey: "transform")

        for i in 0 ..< 5 {
            lines[i].addAnimation(lineStrokeStart, forKey: "strokeStart")
            lines[i].addAnimation(lineStrokeEnd, forKey: "strokeEnd")
            lines[i].addAnimation(lineOpacity, forKey: "opacity")
        }

        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

If I understand it right the first `select()` should toggle the *animate* to `true`?

But if I change it to :

```
public func select() {
    selected = true
}
```

The app will run without crashing but the animation wont be run.

So what does `select(true)` do?

Comment: You need to include the code where you're setting up a `#selector`.  Also, the any other methods name `select` you have, because *this* code won't even compile.  (You'd have to call `select(animate: true)`)

Comment: It would compile, `UIResponder` has a `select:` method

Comment: @dan That assumes that this code is part of a class which inherits from `UIResponder`.  It's probably a relatively safe bet, but that context is entirely missing here.  This question is significantly lacking in details.

Comment: @nhgrif He posted a link to the source of the library hes using

Comment: @dan He wants free help.  Why should I go dig through some random library to give it to him?

Comment: @nhgrif You don't have to, it's only 1 file though.  My point was that I know his class inherits from `UIResponder` because I looked at it.

Comment: @dan Oh, gotcha, sorry.  For the record, I generally don't click *any* links away from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding the signature of the method:

```
public func select() {
    select(animate: true)
}
```

Otherwise the method declaration can be modified as

`public func select(animate: Bool)`

Therefore,

```
public func select() {
    select(true)
}
```

will be valid for complie